# SwipeJS doesn't work in JQuery-Mobile web-application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I try to get SwipeJS (www.swipejs.com) running on my JQuery-Mobile site.

```
  <script src="bin/js/swipe.js"></script>      
   <style>  
      /* Swipe 2 required styles */  
      .swipe {
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }
      .swipe-wrap {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }
      .swipe-wrap > div {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        position: relative;
      } 
      /* END required styles */  
      </style>
```

--

```
<!-- PAGE -->
<div data-role="page" id="pagec" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-id="head2" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <?php getNav(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<div data-role="content">
  <!-- SWIPE -->
  <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><b>0</b></div>
    <div><b>1</b></div>
    <div><b>2</b></div>
    <div><b>3</b></div>
    <div><b>4</b></div>
    <div><b>5</b></div>
    <div><b>6</b></div>
    <div><b>7</b></div>
    <div><b>8</b></div>
    <div><b>9</b></div>
    <div><b>10</b></div>
    <div><b>11</b></div>
    <div><b>12</b></div>
    <div><b>13</b></div>
    <div><b>14</b></div>
    <div><b>15</b></div>
    <div><b>16</b></div>
    <div><b>17</b></div>
    <div><b>18</b></div>
    <div><b>19</b></div>
    <div><b>20</b></div>
  </div>
  </div>



  <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>

    <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button> 
    <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>

  </div>
  <?php getContent(); ?>  
  <!-- //SWIPE -->    
</div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <?php getForm(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //PAGE -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='swipe.js'></script>
<script>

// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  // startSlide: 4,
  // auto: 3000,
  // continuous: true,
  // disableScroll: true,
  // stopPropagation: true,
  // callback: function(index, element) {},
  // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});

// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');

</script>
```

The swipe.js is linked in the included header.php and the required css is added aswell. Although everything is implemented as described in the instructions, it doesn't work.

The demo is working fine...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in the head and TADAAAAA... It works.

```
 $(document).on('pageshow', function () {
  var elem = document.getElementById('content_swipe');
  window.content_swipe = Swipe(elem, {
    // startSlide: 1,
    // auto: 3000,
    // continuous: true,
    // disableScroll: true,
    // stopPropagation: true,
    // callback: function(index, element) {},
    // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
  });
  // with jQuery
  // window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that in the new versions of JQM, pageshow event is deprecated. You can use a new event:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event, ui) {  
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('content_swipe'));   
});
```